# Custom post type with tags

Tags: custom-post-types, tags, archives, pre-get-posts

My understanding is, that custom post types can share tags with the posts also.

I have created tags and applied them to a blog post and a custom post type.

Yet when I click on a tag it only returns blog posts.

I have this line in my register post type:

```
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
```

But I also have this outside of the function

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'projects');
```

Are they doing the same thing? Also why will it not return custom posts with that tag?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both assignments do the same, but the `post_tag` archive is using the post type `post` only by default. Don’t worry, there is a hook for you: `pre_get_posts`.

Example with tags for pages:

```
// register tags for pages
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse_75297_register_tags_for_pages' );

function wpse_75297_register_tags_for_pages()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' );
}

// add post type 'page' to tax query
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_75297_add_pages_to_tax_query' );
function wpse_75297_add_pages_to_tax_query( $query )
{
    if ( ! is_main_query() or ! is_tag() )
        return $query;

    $query->set('post_type', array('page','post'));

    return $query;
}
```

Make sure the post type is spelled correctly. If your post type is `project` you cannot use `projects` in another filter.